# Laravel: Undefined variable: request

Tags: laravel, authentication, request

I don´t can find the problem. Where ist it? "Undefined variable: request"

```
public function login()
{
  // Validate the form data
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'passwort' => 'required|min:6'
  ]);

  // Attempt to log the user in
  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'passwort' => $request->passwort], $remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(roue('admin.dashboard'));
  }

  // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

Comment: Well, pretty straightforward. You have not defined the 'request' variable but you are using it in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to inject `Request` object:

```
public function login(Request $request)
```

Also, add this line to the top of your class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Alternatively, you can just use `request()` instead of `$request` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the 'request' variable but you are using it in your code.

Edited Code

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  // Validate the form data
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'passwort' => 'required|min:6'
  ]);

  // Attempt to log the user in
  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'passwort' => $request->passwort], $remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(roue('admin.dashboard'));
  }

  // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

Also, add this line to the top of your class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```